# Which pattern would match for 1x1 matrix?

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, pattern-matching

I'm writing a predicate to check if a matrix is (square) **lower triangular**.

The **idea** is to return *true* if all elements of the *first* row (except the element at index 0) are all zero, and then call again the predicate on the **sub-matrix** obtained *excluding* 1 row and 1 column. Recursion should end when the submatrix is just 1 number (e.g. [[x]]) which is of course lower triangular.

Question: how can I match [[x]] where x is just a number?

```
lowertriangular (???) = True
lowertriangular (x:xs) = all (==0) (tail x) && lowertriangular (map tail xs)
```

**Edit**:

```
m = [[1,0,0],[2,-3,0],[4,5,6]]

lt m = all (==0) [0, 0] && lt [[-3, 0], [5, 6]]
     = all (==0) [0, 0] && (all (==0) [0] && lt [6])
```

lt [6] should match [[_]] that returns True.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match `[[x]]` using the pattern `[[x]]` - or `[[_]]` since you don't actually care about the value of `x`. I.e.

```
lowertriangular [[_]] = True
```

will return true when called with a 1x1 matrix.

---

However it should be noted that the 1x1 matrices are already perfectly handled by the case `lowertriangular (x:xs) = ...`, so there's no need for you to handle them explicitly. What you need to handle is the case where you get an empty list, like this:

```
lowertriangular [] = True
```

Comment: @sepp2k: nope, if I use [[_]] I get "Non-exhaustive patterns in function lowertrinagular".

Comment: @Gremo: You get that because you're not matching the case where the list is empty (i.e. a 0x0 matrix). However your question was how to handle a 1x1 matrix and this is the answer to that.

Comment: Gremo: That would probably be because you have something besides one element in your inner list (you're only matching for a list of a list of one element).  sepp2k's answer is still valid, but you have other issues too.

Comment: @sepp2k: see my edits in first post. When lowertriangular is supposed to be called with an empty matrix?

Comment: @Gremo: Sorry, I wasn't thinking. what you need to handle is the case where you get a list containing empty lists.

Comment: @Gremo: Ok, I just thought a bit and I was right the first time. Your base case is the empty list. Assuming the input is always a quadratic matrix, you'll either return False or end up with the empty list eventually.

Comment: @sepp2K: can you explain a bit more why my base case should be empty list? Considering my expanded example in first post.

Comment: @Gremo: Because in your example `lt [[6]]` expand to `all (==0) [] && lowertriangular []` which would expand to `True && True`, which would expand to `True`.  Though you're right that using `[[x]]` would work equally well (except when you're explicitly passing in an empty array). I just tried it and both versions work as expected in ghci without throwing a pattern match exception. So I don't know why it didn't work for you the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
lowertriangular (x:[]) = True
lowertriangular (x:xs) = all (==0) (tail x) && lowertriangular (map tail xs)
```

Comment: With this implementation a call `lowertriangular [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1]]` results in `True`, while a call to, e. g., `lowertriangular [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1]]` results in 'False`, because the last element of the second row is `1` (not zero). It returns `False`, when called with an empty matrix.

Comment: @sepp2k: Isn't your `[]:xs` is identical to `x:[]` now ? :-/

Comment: @sepp2k: I was thinking from the practical point of view with respect to that problem :-) Not matter.